# informix + Fatal error in shared memory creation

Tags: linux, database, informix

please advice how to solve this problem
I have linux with informix DB
its fail on - Fatal error in shared memory creation

```
su - informix
```

-sh-2.05b$ oninit -v

```
    ONCONFIG /usr/informix/etc/onconfig.active is not owned by user with id 4000.
    Checking group membership to determine server run modesucceeded
    Reading configuration file '/usr/informix/etc/onconfig.active'...succeeded
    Creating /INFORMIXTMP/.infxdirs ... succeeded
     Creating infos     file "/usr/informix/etc/.infos.active_trm" ... "/usr/informix/etc/.conf.active_trm" ... s succeeded
    Writing to infos file ... succeeded
    Checking config parameters...succeeded
    Allocating and attaching to shared memory...FAILED
    oninit: Fatal error in shared memory creation
```

oninit -i

```
  This action will initialize IBM Informix Dynamic Server;
   any existing IBM Informix Dynamic Server databases will NOT be accessible -
   Do you wish to continue (y/n)? 
   please enter 'y' or 'n'...
   Do you wish to continue (y/n)? y
   oninit: Fatal error in shared memory creation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shared memory segments may not have cleared properly. Run onclean -ky command. This should hopefully clear any lingering shared memory segments.

If this doesn't work, run ipcs command to identify the memory segments and remove using ipcrm

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have rights `660` on your `ROOTPATH` file, see the location on `$INFORMIX/etc/[your_onconfig]`.

Launch `oninit -ivy` for more details or see log on your `MSGPATH` file.